# What type of matrix guarantees positive-definiteness in complex inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, sesquilinear-forms

It can be shown that any (complex) inner product on $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ can be written as $\langle v,w\rangle=\bar v^{T}Aw$ for some $n\times n$ matrix $A$.

Conversely suppose we consider $F:V\times V\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $F(v,w)=\bar{v}^{T}Aw$, when is $F$ an (complex) inner product? (In other words, we need sesquilinear form, conjugate symmetry and positive-definiteness)

Now imposing conjugate symmetry and non-degeneracy, we can deduce $A=\overline{A^t}$ and $\det(A)\not =0.$
However this is not enough as I considered a few examples that do not satisfy positive-definiteness. Hence what matrix would guarantee such positive-definiteness? Do we need the determinant to be greater than $0?$

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: All the eigenvalues must be positive. This is a straightforward deduction from the spectral theorem.

Comment: The inner product is positive definite if and only if the matrix $A$ is "positive definite" in the sense [discussed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix)